# adb doesn't find smartphone stuck on Error during encrypting

Tags: adb, encryption

I have a ZTE unlocked  stuck on error during encrypting:

It doesn't reboot into recovery mode using the hardware keys combination, it just start up and then reboot into normal mode leading me back to the error page, if I choose to reset on the error page nothing happens.

I have tried to link it to the computer and use adb but the device cannot be found.
I think the problem is that it doesn't have usb debug enabled.

Any suggestion would be great